# Automatically not emphasizing references inside propositions

Tags: cross-referencing, emphasis

Is there a way to make reference not emphasized in proposition ?

For propositions I used the standart AMS packages, so everything is emphasized in it. Thus, when I insert a reference, it also displays an emphasized number, i.e. "*(1)*". But I don't want it to be emhpasized. Now of course I could use \emph{\ref{...}} inside to proposition so that the two emphaszing command annihilate each other and the reference is displayed as "(1)", but I wouldn't want to do that, since it a big document that gets tedious.

Comment: When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone.

Comment: For equations, use `\eqref{}` without `()`. It will be automatically inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is as easy as `\usepackage{upref}`

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{upref}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}\label{T:One}
  This is an important result.
\end{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}
  This result is not as important as~\ref{T:One}.
\end{Theorem}

Here is a normal \ref{T:One}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, both your and Andrew solution solve the problem for ref - but the problem is unfortunaley more involved as I see now, since I actually use LyX, not LaTeX right now, and LyX somehow can't use eqref - and the solution from this answer unfortunately doesn't work: http://bit.ly/1wYaLFh  as it produces an error. So when I want paranthesis around, LyX actually uses (\ref{...}). By your solution then 1 displays perfectly non-emphasized, but the paranthesis are still emphasized. Is there a way to also make the paranthesis non-emphasized (or ideally get Lyx to use \eqref ?

Comment: @user10324 If LyX doesn't allow `\eqref` the route is simple: abandon it. Sorry, but the tools should serve people not the contrary.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused by your question because `\ref{}` will produce `1` with emphasis, but without brackets `(1)`, whereas `\eqref{}` produces `(1)`  *without* emphasis. That is, neither of them will lead to `(1)` being typeset with emphasis... perhaps this is a function of the other packages that you are using? (This is one of the reasons why it is good to always supply a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) .)

As `\eqref{}` already does what you want I'll show one way of making `\ref{}` print `1` without using emphasis. You said that you were using AMS packages so I have used `amsart` as the documentclass. In this case theorem are, ultimately, produced by `\@begintheorem` so I redefine this so that it defines `\ref` to remove (or rather add) emphasis inside a theorem-ike environment.

Here is some example output:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter% we need this to change the definition of \@begintheorem
\let\real@begintheorem=\@begintheorem% save real AMS theorem environment
\let\real@ref=\ref
\def\@begintheorem#1#2[#3]{%
    \real@begintheorem{#1}{#2}[#3]% start the theorem
    \def\ref##1{\emph{\real@ref{##1}}}% overwrite \ref INSIDE a theormem
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}\label{T:One}
  This is an important result.
\end{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}
  This result is not as important as~\ref{T:One}.
\end{Theorem}

Here is a normal \ref{T:One}.
\end{document}
```

Of course, we could instead use the `\patchcmd` from [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to change `\@begintheorem` but this will end up doing much the same thing as above (after first loading a lot of the commands).

Comment: Thanks, both your and egregs solution solve the problem for ref - but the problem is unfortunaley more involved as I see now, since I actually use LyX, not LaTeX right now, and LyX somehow can't use eqref - and the solution from this answer unfortunately doesn't work: http://bit.ly/1wYaLFh  as it produces an error. So when I want paranthesis around, LyX actually uses (\ref{...}). By your solution then 1 displays perfectly non-emphasized, but the paranthesis are still emphasized. Is there a way to also make the paranthesis non-emphasized (or ideally get Lyx to use \eqref ?

Comment: @user10324 Sorry, but I don't have LyX installed, and I don't use, so I can't advise. Of course, you should have mentioned this on your initial post...

Comment: Yes, I know, sorry :(