# LyX doesn't know `eqref`?

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx, emphasis

LyX somehow can't use `eqref`. (I use version 2.0.2 and wouldn't want to update, if possible, since I've set up everything in a very specific way and wouldn't like a new version to perhaps tamper with that.)
So when I want parenthesis around a number that references some equation, LyX actually uses `(\ref{...})`. This is annoying, because in propositions and theorem (e.g. from the AMS environment), where everything is emphasized, the number that references is emphasized too - whereas by using `eqref` (which can be inserted using "evil red code") this wouldn't be the case.

Now in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210297/automatically-not-emphasizing-references-inside-propositions/210312?noredirect=1#comment491861_210312) answer of mine it was indicated, by using an additional package, how to make the number that  `ref` displays always non-emphasized - but the problem remains the the parenthesis are emphaszied.

Is there a way to also make the paranthesis non-emphasized (or ideally get Lyx to use `\eqref` without "evil red code" ?
The solution from this  [answer](http://bit.ly/1wYaLFh) unfortunately doesn't work for me, as it produces an error.

Comment: Does the doc use amsmath in the first place? Without it there is no reason for LyX to use it.

Comment: My impression is that this is more a question about the innards of LyX, so it's better to ask it in a specialized LyX forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the solution to your problem: go to Document > Settings and uncheck "Use refstyle (not prettyref) for cross-references. See the screenshot below

[image]

---

Now some picky comments (feel free to skip these):

In regards to "LyX somehow can't use eqref", I don't agree (see the solution above). Did you mean that as a question? I like to help users ask clearer questions. I understand that it is difficult for many non-native speakers and they seem to appreciate suggestions. The way I would phrase this is "Can LyX somehow use eqref?"

Also, in your posts can you please give minimal examples? See here for more information: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Thank you for giving the version of LyX that you are using. It is often also useful to say what operating system you are using and its version (e.g. "Ubuntu 14.04").

And my last bit of unsolicited advice is in response to your statement that you do not want to upgrade (note that you are using a version of LyX that is 3 years old). If you plan on using computers for a while it is very stressful to not have a backup plan. That is, I would suggest investing time into setting up your computer such that if you install a new version and that version does not work for you you can easily go back to what you had before. I've never had problems with this on Linux, and it is nice because it is never stressful to decide "should I upgrade or not?" because I can always go back. I imagine that Mac and Windows have ways of dealing with such concerns also. That said, if you don't have such a setup, I agree with you that you could run into problems when upgrading LyX.

Comment: Does this method use `\eqref` just for equations and `\ref` for the other cross references?

Comment: @egreg If you choose "(<Reference>)" for the particular reference (by right-clicking) and you have the setting I described above as unchecked, `\eqref` will be used for any reference (I believe), such as a reference to a label that is in a caption in a figure float. Is that bad? Should it only be used for equations?

Comment: Yes, it's bad: `\eqref` adds parentheses that are generally unwanted for references to non equations.

Comment: @egreg I see. Well, LyX does things a little strange (as usual): as far as the user knows, they are choosing between parentheses or no parentheses. They do not choose `\eqref` vs. `(\ref)` (except through the Document Settings). So it works like this: when you insert a reference, the default is no parentheses. If they choose the "(<Reference>)" option, it is because they go out of their way to *choose* to have parentheses. In this case, if "Use refstyle" is not selected, then eqref is used. Does that make sense? If not, I can add a more detailed description in my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure to have understood how it works. If it's impossible to have `\ref` for some references and `\eqref` for others is a notable weakness of the software.

Comment: @egreg It is possible to have `\ref` for some references and `\eqref` for other references (only because some of your references may be parenthesized and others not). It is not possible to have `\ref` for some *parenthesized* references and `\eqref` for other *parenthesized* references. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution; unchecking that solved everything! LyX never ceases to amaze me :) Actually I was convinced that LyX couldn't use `eqref` because when searching this issue on google, several people on different forums seemed to have the same problem, so I assumend `\ref` was standart. 

1)
 I also am not sure if I understood the difference between checking the box or not correctly: If it's checked, then basically `(\ref)` is used when  "(<Reference>)"  is selected and `(\eqref)` is used, when "Formatted reference" is selected.  [...]

Comment: [...] When it's not checked, then *only* things that change are these two options and now in the first case, one then uses `\eqref` and in the second case `\prettyref`, right ? 2) This is slightly off-topic, but I indeed use Ubuntu (12.04), but am not aware of any backup-solution that's really stable and useable (though I might be willing to upgrade Ubuntu if that provides me with some backup possibilities). Do you maybe have a suggestion for a good automatical backup program like the restore points on Windows ? [...]

Comment: [...] 3) BTW, I think we "know" each other since I filed once a bug report under something like "math_lyx_user" on LyX and, if I remember correctly, you took care of it :)

Comment: @user10324 Yes, I think you understand the difference well (at least as far as I understand it). As far as several people on different forums having the same problem, it would have been great to link to those posts in your question. Good to know that we fixed a bug you reported! Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Ah, you are on Ubuntu also? Great! Well, in this case it is easy. Add the LyX PPA: http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3 . First, do *not* upgrade `lyx` because that will upgrade your 2.0.2. Instead, install the packages `lyx2.0` and `lyx2.1`. These will give separate installations of LyX. If you want to run LyX 2.0.8.1, just use the command lyx2.0. And if you want to run LyX 2.1.2, use the command lyx2.1. For example, they have different user directories (e.g. `~/.lyx2.0`). If you have any other questions, please email lyx-users@lists.lyx.org .